# Как сделать длинный пробел?

Tags: html

Я пробовал вот это `&nbsp`, но это - не длинный, что мне делать?

Comment: Ответ Yura Ivanov гораздо более правильный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это Html.
Первый способ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Второй способ <span style='padding-left:10px;'> </span> Text

Comment: а если мне надо снизу ?

Comment: ` <span style='padding-bottom: 10px;'> </span>`

Answer (score 25):

```
&nbsp; неразрывный пробел
&thinsp; узкий пробел (применяют в двойных словах)
&ensp; средний, разрывной пробел
&emsp; длинный разрывной пробел (примеяют в конце предложений)
```

- [HTML-верстка::Верстка - F.A.Q.](http://xpoint.ru/forums/internet/html_css/markup/faq.xhtml)
- [Wikipedia: Пробел](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пробел)